# string: syntax error on raspbian jelly, flawless on IDLE windows 8

Tags: string, syntax

My script (python 3.6) raises an error when executed on my RPI (Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047), but runs flawlessly when executed with IDLE, on a windows 8.1 PC.

Basically, I want to create a gzip archive from "data.json" file.

Here is a light version:

```
import time
import gzip

inputFile = "/path/to/data.json"

dataArchiveName = f"{inputFile}-{time.localtime().tm_mday}_{time.localtime().tm_mon}_{time.localtime().tm_year}.gz"

...
```

When I run the script, the following exception is raised:

```
File "dataManager2.py", line 96
dataArchiveName = f"{inputFile}-{time.localtime().tm_mday}_{time.localtime().tm_mon}_{time.localtime().tm_year}.gz"
                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I do not understand why... Any idea ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What Python version do you have on RPi, it looks like it doesn't support f-strings (<= 3.5).

Comment: python3 --version
Python 3.5.3
But maybe f strings were added in 3.6 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)s were introduced in Python 3.6, since you are using Python 3.5 on you Raspberry Pi, you will have to either install Python 3.6 on it or use older way of formatting strings, this should work:

```
dataArchiveName = "%s-%s_%s_%s.gz" % (inputFile, time.localtime().tm_mday, time.localtime().tm_mon, time.localtime().tm_year)
```

Comment: Ok, you were right indeed.
I chose the update option, and it works, but thank you for the old-style version :)